# how to differentiate a string vs url with python type hints?

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, python-typing

I'd like to be able to differentiate between functions that return a URL vs a plain string (eg a local filepath vs a remote http URL)

Is there a way to do this with python type hints / [PEP484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/)?

```py
def myfun() -> str:
    return "https://example.com/foo"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem appropriate for type hints, unless you define a class for holding URLs instead of using strings.

Comment: You could use `typing`'s `TypeVar` but that would only "trick" the type hinter, the actual type would still be `str`. Best case would be to describe a Class for Url's